# Find a number in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, nullpointerexception

There is an `ArrayList` "allVariables" that contain an array of integers. I need to find if this array contains the number 1. If it does, the answer should be false, otherwise true.

I wrote some code, but it results in `java.lang.NullPointerException`:

```
private boolean notIncluded(int ind, ArrayList<Color> c) {
    ArrayList<Integer[]> allVariables = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
        // Filling the ArryList

    for (int k = 0; k < c.size(); k++) {
        allVariables.add(c.get(k).getColor()); // returns Integer[]
    }

    if (Arrays.asList(allVariables).contains(1)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Please show us your stacktrace?

Comment: got some objection to `.contains`?

Comment: allVariables is already a list, why do you need to do Arrays.asList(..) again? are you sure parameter 'c' is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check for nulls in your code. The following piece of code attempts implementation of what you need and checks for nulls in the process:

```
public function allVariablesContains(List<Integer[]> allVariables, int intToSearchFor)
{
    if (allVariables == null)
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < allVariables.Length; i++)
    {
        if (allVariables[i] == null)
            continue;
        if (Arrays.asList(allVariables).contains(intToSearchFor))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For containment checks, don't use a `List` data strcture. This is exactly why we have `Set` (or more specifically `HashSet` in your case).

If you can find a way to map `ind` to a `Color` instance, you can get very quick "inclusion" checks.

Comment: Provided that the value is not contained more the once in the list, in whose this recommendation would not work and the list would be more appropriate.

Comment: @edalorzo: As a general rule of thumb, when it comes to searching stuff, `List` is almost always a bad solution since it ignores the contents of the object which can be used to "tune" the search. A better thing in this case would be revisit the class design and make it such that it's "search" friendly. For e.g. we can use the integer constituents of `Color` to calculate the `hashCode` which in turn can be used to quickly locate the bucket of probable `Color` instances. After that, it wouldn't be that bad to fall back to an expensive `equals()` check.

Comment: Saying that list is a bad solution when it comes to searching is actually a bold affirmation. At any rate, my argument is that a Set will not work if the list is intended to have repeated elements.

Comment: @edalorzo: It's not a bold one, it's a tried and tested one, also one backed by the fundamentals of complexity theory. Stuff millions of elemets into the list and watch your program choke and die as it traverses the entire list every time just for a simple "containment" check. Anyways, my post was meant to provide food for thought to the OP which I think I have done. I rest my case.

Answer (score 1):

Try performing a null check on `c` and `c.get(k)`.

Answer (score 1):

`Arrays.asList(allVariables)` : allVariables is not an array, it is a List of arrays!